# Call stack info on new thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

When we invoke the start() then a new thread of execution starts with dedicated call stack.

I'm wondering which is going to be the first method in that call stack: start() or run().

It's mentioned that the Thread is considered to be dead once run() completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start()` isn't called on the new thread at all; it only runs on the original thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thread can be considered live once start() has been invoked. It seems a bit contradicting.. Does it mean that state 'live' doesn't mean a new stack?

Comment: It does, but the `start()` method does not appear on the new stack.

Comment: @Firefox Just think about it that way: A method is pushed onto the thread's call stack when it is called. Since you only create the new thread IN the start method, there's no way it could appear on the newly created thread's stack (ok that's a lie, sure it could, but it doesn't make a lot of sense)

Comment: Thanks Voo, your comment clarifies it for me.

Comment: @Firefox Fine. btw if you prepend an @ sign to a username the user is automatically informed about your post.

Answer (score 3):

`start` is a method call on the main thread. This means it is on the stack of the main thread. Then inside `start` a new thread is actually fired and the `run` method is the first method on the new thread's stack.